# How do I plan the cycle routes so that I avoid major roads?

Tags: route-setting, bikepacking

I'm going on a 1400 km cycle tour this summer and I'm wondering how to plan a cycle tour without taking major roads. When I enter the routes on Komoot, for example, I am guided along major roads (which is not so cool from experience)

i would prefer to take long-distance cycle paths or small country roads